# ItextSharp Columntext in my PDF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, text, itext

i´m working at a little program.
I have a PDF with 17 pages and i want to place columntext on some of them.
But after creating the PDF i get only Page one out.

```
{
        string newfile = "newfile.pdf";

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(newfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        PdfReader reader = null;
        PdfWriter writer = null;
        PdfImportedPage page = null;
        Document dc = null;

        dc = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(dc, fs);
        dc.Open();
        int numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);


        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
        {
            page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, startPage);
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            if (startPage == 1)
            {
                cb.BeginText();
                ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(new Chunk("<<NAME>>", FontFactory.GetFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf", 15, BaseColor.BLACK)).SetSkew(0, 10)), 367.7F, 140.7F, 10);
                cb.EndText();
            }
            startPage++;
        }
        dc.Close();
        fs.Close();
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();

    }
```

#### Addition originally posted as answer

I tried to use stamper but the PDF file ist damaged. Something is wrong with my code string newfile = "newfile2.pdf";

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(newfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        PdfReader reader = null;
        reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,fs);
        int numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        PdfContentByte cb;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
        {
            cb = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(new Chunk("<<NAME>>", FontFactory.GetFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf", 15, BaseColor.BLACK)).SetSkew(0, 10)), 367.7F, 140.7F, 10);
        }

        fs.Close();
        reader.Close();
```

Comment: Step 1 (*mandatory*): Throw away your current code. Step 2 (*optional*): curse the person who gave you this code (it's an idiot). Step 3: use `PdfStamper` if you want to add content to an existing document.

Comment: I tried stamper but the PDF doesnt apply my columntext. Also used smartcopy but the same

Comment: Don't use `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy` if you only have one PDF. I repeat: use `PdfStamper`. If done correctly, the text will be added. If that "doesn't work" then you're doing it wrong. Note that your choice of method is strange. I'd never use the method that requires `BeginText()` and `EndText()` in your simple use case. I think you're creating illegal PDF syntax by nesting text objects, but who am I to judge? I'm only the original developer of iText.

Comment: *"I tried stamper but the PDF doesnt apply my columntext"* - the stamper is the way to go. If you had problems with that, why don't you simply post your code of that attempt?

Comment: I don't understand the comment *"Added selectpages and document and it works"* to your deleted answer, though.